# IntelliJ does not hit Breakpoint but code is executed (console shows println)

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, functional-programming, breakpoints

Why is IntelliJ unable to debug the line 
`println(s"foo: $nr")`
in the code below?
Am I doing something wrong?

When I remove/comment the line 
`val neverUsed = () => f`
debugging works just fine and the execution stops with the debugger window just as expected.

```
object Test {

  def wrap(f: Int => String): Int => String = {

    val foo = (nr: Int) => {

      println(s"foo: $nr") // <--- Breakpoint added here!

      // This declaration seems to prevent debugging.
      // when removed or commented out debugging works as expected.
      val neverUsed = () => f

      s"FOO $nr"
    }

    nr: Int => foo(nr)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(wrap(_.toString)(123))
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it successfully stops at the breakpoint both with or without the line you pointed to. Try invalidating the cache by  > `File | Invalidate Caches/Restart`. A silly question: are you sure you are on debug mode instead of normal run mode?

Answer (score 0):

[dionysis-nt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4230761/dionysis-nt) was right. It was a problem of my local IntelliJ installation. So nothing wrong about the code above.